# Change the background-color of the whole app on button click React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to change the color of the background of my whole React App on button click. However, I only change the color of the button itself. I am importing the App.css into my app and I want to dynamically change the CSS of the App from a separate function called ChangeColor. This function is then placed in my Header.js that is then placed in the App.js

Is there a way that I can do this? This is my code:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/esm/Button";
import '../../../App.css'

function ChangeColor() {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsActive(current => !current);
    };

    return(
        <Button 
            style={{
                backgroundColor: isActive ? 'red' : '',
                color: isActive ? 'white' : '',
            }}
            onClick={handleClick}
        > Test </Button>
    )
}

export default ChangeColor
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: The app component should have a prop for the color of the app, then when the botton is clicked change the color prop of the app, and in the app component manage this like you did in the button component.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. Do you want to manage the bgcolor with state, or do you want to directly access the stylesheet and update that?

Comment: @Andy I was planning to do it with state, but I think that it makes more sense to update the stylesheet. I am not sure, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions that come to mind.

1. Store the background color in state, and toggle between the colours depending on the current state.

(Small note - you shouldn't call your component `ChangeColor` as it's not really representative of what the component *is* - `changeColor` might be a good name for a function. You should call your component `ButtonChangeColor`, for example.)

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('white');

  function toggleBackground() {
    if (bgColor === 'white') setBgColor('black');
    if (bgColor === 'black') setBgColor('white');
  }

  const appStyle = ['App', bgColor].join(' ');

  return (
    <div className={appStyle}>
      <button onClick={toggleBackground}>
        Toggle background
      </button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.App {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.black { background-color: black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

2. Use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and modify the current stylesheet using the [CSSStyleDeclaration interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) - no state required. We can usefully maintain the `toggleBackground` function outside of the component because it doesn't rely on state to work.

```js
function toggleBackground() {
  const { style } = document.documentElement;
  const bgColor = style.getPropertyValue('--bg-color');
  if (bgColor === 'white' || bgColor === '') {
    style.setProperty('--bg-color', 'black');
  } else {
    style.setProperty('--bg-color', 'white');
  }
}

function Example() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={toggleBackground}>
        Toggle background
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
:root { --bg-color: white; }

.App {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: The second version worked very well for me. Thank you very much Andy!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are acting on the properties of the button. Instead you **should act on the element its color you are trying to change**.

In this code snippet the button modifies the color of the `root` div. **Be aware that this solution is just to illustrate your problem**. As has been stated by other users there are many ways to achieve what you want and some adhere to best practices while others not. Given the context of the question this answer just to points to **why it is not working** and not **how best to do it**. Please, refer to [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73827571/11768882) for more information about the latter.

```js
const App = () => {
  const changeAppColor = () => {
    let el = document.getElementById("root");
    if (el.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "unset";
    } else {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <button onClick={changeAppColor}>
        Change color
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id='root'> </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: doesn't react says that is bad to edit element of the dom directly? (i.e use getElementById)

Comment: This is just to illustrate that the color change should target and not the button itself

Comment: although is a valid code, it is not the right way to do it, and we don't know if he will be able to understand this code and write a completly different one. I mean he might even need to use providers for this.

Comment: @AlanWillianDuarte You are right about that. The solutions are multiple but in my opinion the problem of his code is just that it is not targeting the right element. I will edit my answer as to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

you can store isActive and color in `localStorage`

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(localStorage.getItem('is_active') || false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsActive(current => !current);
    };


<Button 
      style={{
          backgroundColor: isActive ? 'red' : '',
          color: isActive ? localStorage.getItem('bg_color') : '',
      }}
      onClick={handleClick}
  > Test </Button>
```